# component.find("edit").get("e.recordSave") returns null

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I want to edit a record in lightning then I created this component. The reason because I'm not using the standard because I want to have control when the user clicks on save.

Cmp

```
<force:recordEdit aura:id="edit" recordId="{!v.recordId}"/>
<ui:button label="Save" press="{!c.save}"/>
```

Controller

```
 save : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.find("edit").get("e.recordSave").fire(); // Works in record home page but not in a lightning component

       //redirect

}
```

When I added the component in a record home is working but when I calling the same component from a VF that doesn't work.
I'm opening the lightining component in the following way. Notice this component will be opened in Lightning Experience

```
var stringToEncode = '{"componentDef":"c:myComponent","attributes":{"recordId":"a02D0000006V8Ni"}}';
var encodedData = window.btoa(stringToEncode);
window.parent.location = '/one/one.app#' + encodedData;
```

component.find("edit").get("e.recordSave") returns null

Comment: Is the {v.recordId} a typo? It should be {!v.recorId} you are missing the binding operator !

Comment: Did you ever find out why get("e.recordSave") is returning null? Facing the same problem.

Comment: I've just noticed that immediately after I upload a new change to Salesforce and refresh the browser, get("e.recordSave") returns a good object. If I then do some testing in the browser and force a browser refresh again without deploying to Salesforce, get("e.recordSave") then always returns null. Then every time I deploy a new build to Salesforce, get("e.recordSave") comes back with a good object

Answer (score 2):

This is a Lightning Experience and Salesforce1 event only.

> This event is handled by the one.app container. It’s supported in
>   Lightning Experience and Salesforce1 only.

Ref [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_recordSave.htm)

To determine if this event is going to work for you, you need to use one of the Visualforce globals and pass it into your component - or get it from your apex controller.

Controller code:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static getUIThemeDescription() {
  return UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed();
}
```

JS Controller action handler:

```
if (result == 'Theme4d') {
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I knew that. It's in lightning experience.

Comment: No, that's not true. You said in your question that you called the component from VF. By definition, you are NOT in Lightning Experience if in a VF page, no matter how you accessed that page. It's a different namespace and the even you are trying to fire does not exist within it.

Comment: Sorry but It's calling the component from a VF but is not on a VF. If you see my code window.parent.location = '/one/one.app#' + encodedData is redirecting to   LEX. /one/one.app opens a page in LEX.